# MariaDB Subquery

Tags: mysql, laravel, mariadb

Good day!

I have this SQL but is not working in hosting. On LAN everything is fine. I couldn't find what the problem is. 
Laravel project SQL:

```php
$data = DB::select('
            SELECT 
                DATE(o.created_at) as day,
                count(id) as count_all,
                count((SELECT id WHERE status=3)) as success,
                count((SELECT id WHERE status=5)) as return_order,
                count((SELECT id WHERE status=0 or status=4 or status=8)) as call_order,

                count((SELECT id WHERE status=7 or status=6 or status=1)) as otkaz,
                count((SELECT id WHERE status=2)) as nado_dostavit,

                SUM((SELECT offer_price)) as all_price,
                SUM((SELECT offer_price WHERE status=3)) as success_price,
                SUM((SELECT offer_price WHERE status=5)) as return_order_price,
                SUM((SELECT offer_price WHERE status=0 or status=4 or status=8)) as call_order_price,
                SUM((SELECT offer_price WHERE status=7 or status=6 or status=1)) as otkaz_price,
                SUM((SELECT offer_price WHERE status=2 )) as nado_dostavit_price,
                (SELECT sum(s.visitors) FROM statistics as s WHERE s.offer_id='.$user_id.') as visitors
            FROM 
                orders as o
            WHERE 
                  offer_id='.$user_id.'
                  AND  created_at between "'.$mother_later.'" AND "'.$today.'"
            GROUP BY day
            ORDER BY day desc
            limit 30
    ');
```

> ERROR:
>
> (2/2) QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an 
>       error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
>       MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 
>       status=3)) as success,

Comment: SELECTs normally include a FROM clause, so the notion that 'everything is fine' seems doubtful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your subqueries have `FROM` clauses, which is why you are getting a syntax error. However you don't actually want subqueries in those positions. For the `COUNT`, you should replace them with e.g.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN status=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

and for the `SUM`s, you should use e.g.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN status=3 THEN offer_price ELSE 0 END)
```

So in total, you query should be:

```
$data = DB::select('
        SELECT 
            DATE(o.created_at) as day,
            count(id) as count_all,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as success,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as return_order,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status=0 OR status=4 OR status=8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as call_order,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status=7 OR status=6 OR status=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as otkaz,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nado_dostavit,

            SUM(offer_price) as all_price,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status=3 THEN offer_price ELSE 0 END) as success_price,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status=5 THEN offer_price ELSE 0 END) as return_order_price,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status=0 OR status=4 OR status=8 THEN offer_price ELSE 0 END)  as call_order_price,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status=7 OR status=6 OR status=1 THEN offer_price ELSE 0 END) as otkaz_price,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status=2 THEN offer_price ELSE 0 END) as nado_dostavit_price,
            (SELECT sum(s.visitors) FROM statistics as s WHERE s.offer_id='.$user_id.') as visitors
        FROM 
            orders as o
        WHERE 
              offer_id='.$user_id.'
              AND  created_at between "'.$mother_later.'" AND "'.$today.'"
        GROUP BY day
        ORDER BY day desc
        limit 30
');
```

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN status=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` can be shortened to `SUM(status=3)`

Comment: @RickJames you're absolutely right. I was just trying to be more generic.